# Why is the maximum number of images i can download from Google using BeautifulSoup only 20?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, web-crawler, google-crawlers

I am trying to scrap images from google and download them into a folder.But Google only gives me 20 results and never more than that even when i change the limit. 
Selenium works fine, but i want to know why it this is not working. 
Please help!

this is my code

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import sys
import random
import urllib

query=input("Enter the keyword to search for :")
query2 = query.replace(' ','%20')

headers={'user-agent':'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:60.0)        Gecko/20100101 Firefox/60.0'}

url="http://www.google.com/search?q="+query2+"&tbm=isch"
start = 0 
while start <50: 
 page=requests.get(url,headers)
 start=start+4

soup=BeautifulSoup(page.text,'html.parser')
list2=soup.find_all('img',limit=21,recursive=True)

i=0
print(len(list2))
while i<len(list2):
 file=list2[i]['src']
 print(list2[i]['src'])
 full_file_name = query+'image'+str(i)
 urllib.request.urlretrieve(file,full_file_name)
 i=i+1
```

Comment: Perhaps google doesn't like it that automatic parsers crawl and request images automatically. So to reduce computation time on their side they might have limited it to 20... Another explanation could be that google only loads more images after scrolling down and thus limiting the initial request to 20.

Comment: BeautifulSoup is just an HTMLparser; it has nothing to do with fetching the HTML from Google in the first place. `requests` does that.

Comment: So what should be the modification with respect to the code and requests?